# My variables and obvervations are reversed in R because of my csv. I have a problem on Csv or Excel

Tags: r, excel, csv

I want to analyse prices of private fixed investments in usa. So i downloaded my data's excel and i converted my excel to csv. But i see 1 observation and 67 variables. Normally it must be inverse (67 observations and 1 variable or 2 variables (with date)) Because my excel composed to date and price. Therefore i share my excel's pictures. First picture which i coverted to csv. Second picture is orginal which i downloaded from official website.

Original data:
[image]

Converted to CSV:
[image]

In R:
[image]

Comment: You can read Excel files into R direclty using the `readxl` package. `mydata <- read_excel("path/to/my/file.xlsx")` https://readxl.tidyverse.org/

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Both data and code should be in text, not images. Your screenshot shows clear syntax errors being flagged for you (`$` with nothing after), which you should take care of first

Answer (score 0):

In R you can transpose the data frame by:

```
new_data <- t(base)
```

with base being the name of your data.frame in R Studio.

Comment: thanks for your comment. you are perfect but when i write your command, everthing is going perfect but column names are being Null and i can't analyze or use command plot... I think that my csv's shape is not true.